# Как добавить placeholder и перенос строки в django форме?

Tags: html, python, django

Как добавить planceholder и перенос строки в django форме? Потому что это: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]смотрится не красиво.
Код forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    sender = forms.EmailField()
```

Код html:

```
<form method="post" action="wassend/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```

После дополнения кода, как указано ниже выдаётся лишний текст.
Код forms.py:

```
from django import forms
class PlaceholderForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaceholderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for _, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.help_text
class ContactForm(PlaceholderForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="Subject...")
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, help_text="Message...")
    sender = forms.EmailField(help_text="Your email...")
```

Код html:

```
<form method="post" action="wassend/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <span class="help_text">Something</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Send message">
</form>
```

Как его можно убрать? Потому, что через span если писать, то пишется не placeholder-ом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить placeholder можно например так:

```
class PlaceholderForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlaceholderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for _, field in self.fields.items():
            field.widget.attrs['placeholder'] = field.help_text


class ContactForm(PlaceholderForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, help_text='Subject')
    ...
```

А переносы либо использованием удобного вам [рендера](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates), например `{{ form.as_p }}`, либо с помощью CSS.

Comment: При использовании этого варианта текст Placeholder-а пишется ещё и рядом с формой. Из-за чего такое могло произойти?

Comment: Атрибут `help_text` рендерится в `span`.

Comment: Если span добавлять там получается не так как надо

Comment: Есть множество решений на основе данного мной ответа. От примитивного `form span { display: none }`, до ручного рендеринга формы или написания собственного рендера. А можно атрибут `placeholder` устанавливать не в конструкторе копированием атрибута `help_text`, а явно в каждом поле.